# COCOS2D Touch detection after application minimisation by gesture(iPad)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Currently I'm fixing an old Cocos2D game. There is a strange problem with it: when the application is being sent to background by the four-finger gesture(iPad) after returning it behaves like the touch began and didn't end, and there no way to end it because the application does not respond to touches. Also when I launch the application and do nothing, the screen becomes locked and after that the application some times does not respond to touches.

I guess that there is something I need to do in the following AppDelegate methods, but I can't figure out exactly:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

    enter code here

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}
```

Comment: Be sure to have touchesCancelled implemented, this may be called when multitasking the app away and if your touch code only handles touchesEnded it will think it's still in "being touched" mode.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the reason